# Necessity of axiom of choice to find discrete function between two functions?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, axiom-of-choice

Let $f,g: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be increasing functions such that $f<g$.

I am interested in obtaining an increasing function $s:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ which is discrete (i.e. $s([0,1])$ countable) with $f \le s < g$.

I can think of a way to do this with Zorn's lemma; by transfinite induction on the following succession of steps:

- Firstly, start at $x = 1$.
- As $f(x) < g(x)$, we can find $0 < q < g(x)-f(x)$. Define $s(t) = g(x) $ on $[1-q, 1]$. (Then, $f \le s < g$ on $[1-q,1]$.)
- Repeat, but now starting at $x = 1-q$.

It is quite easy to see that the obvious poset satisfies the condition for Zorn's lemma (simply take the union of the partially constructed functions) and that the resulting maximal element will then be defined on $[0,1]$. Further, $s$ is seen to be discrete, since each value in its image may be associated to an interval of width $q$, which contains a rational. Thus, $s([0,1]) \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Q}$, and so the image is countable.

**Question**: Is it possible to demonstrate that such a function $s$ exists without the Axiom of (Dependent) Choice? If so, how?

It feels natural to try something like $s = 2^{-n} \lceil 2^n f \rceil$, but this doesn't quite work since, for any $n$, there may exist $t$ such that $g(t)-f(t) < 2^{-n}$. It seems to me that constructing $s$ requires a certain level of flexibility for which Choice is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need any choice.

Enumerate the rational numbers, then $s(x)$ is the least rational number (in the enumeration!) which lies in the interval $(f(x), g(x))$.

Do note, however, that "discrete" is not synonymous with "countable". At all.

Comment: Very neat. Discrete random variables? This is in the context of probability theory.

Comment: Well, I don't know about probability. But discrete comes from a topological context. The rational numbers are countable and not discrete. For example.

Comment: Absolutely. I did want the image to be discrete in the topological sense initially, which is probably why I attempted the approach I did. I later realised it wasn't necessary. But yes, I meant discrete in the probabilistic sense, where I believe the terminology would be considered suitable, if a little deceptive on first glance.

Comment: Excuse me if this is obvious, but is $s$ guaranteed to be increasing?

Comment: @K.Jiang Suppose $y > x$ but $s(y) < s(x)$. Then, $s(y) \in (f(y),g(y))$, so $f(y) < s(y) < s(x)$ and $s(x) < g(x)$, so $s(x) < g(x) \le g(y)$. Therefore, $s(x) \in (f(y),g(y))$ and so $s(x)$ must be later in the enumeration than $s(y)$. But $s(y)$ was not picked for $x$, so it must be the case that $s(y) \not \in (f(x),g(x))$. We certainly have $s(y) > f(y) \ge f(x)$, so the only possibility left is that $s(y) \ge g(x)$. But then, $s(y) \ge g(x) > s(x)$, which is a contradiction. (Throughout, we have used that $f,g$ are increasing.)

Comment: @legionwhale Ah, that makes sense. Thanks!